# On working with PDFBox a external jar to work on PDF docs, getting NoClassDefFound Exception

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Eclipse IDE for my project, where i have added "pdfbox-1.6.0.jar" into External jars of the project. When i wrote code importing the APIs of this jar file, Eclipse didn't show any exceptions. But if i run my program it shows "NoClassDefFound" Exception. 
Can some one help me on this...?

Comment: It is unlikely anyone can help unless you tell us *exactly* what the exception message says, and how you are running the program.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of PDFBox, it is likely that there are runtime dependencies. It would help if you post a more complete question